# How to draw a line between two paragraphs of my text?

Tags: paragraphs, rules

It's just as the title says.

Thanks.

Comment: Some details could be helpful. I understand »sections« as headings thus a part of the document structure. Perhaps you mean the place between two paragraphs.

Comment: @Thorsten: Yes, you are right. I changed the title.

Comment: Also see: [How do I insert a border below text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30973/how-do-i-insert-a-border-below-text/30979#30979)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In ConTeXt, [\blackrule](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Reference/en/blackrule) gives a horizontal line. By default, the width of the line 1em wide and 1ex tall. The width, height, and depth are changed using the respective options. For example:

```
\blackrule[width=\hsize, height=1pt, depth=0.5ex]
```

- Despite its name, `\blackrule` also  draws colored rules.

  ```
  \blackrule[color=red]
  ```
- `\setupblackrules` specifies the options for all `\blackrule`s.
- As a bonus, `\blackrules` (notice the plural) draws multiple horizontal rules. For example:

  ```
  \blackrules[n=6, width=\hsize, distance=0.5ex]
  ```

  draws 6 rules separated by a distance of 0.5ex.

Comment: I think that everyone would agree that this is now the best answer.

Answer (score 38):

How does this look:

[image]

Whilst I generally favour TikZ for *anything* vaguely graphical, this was achieved with a simple `\rule`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\noindent\rule[0.5ex]{\linewidth}{1pt}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

You can thicken the line by changing the `1pt` to something else (or make it thinner, I guess).  Perhaps style purists would want to change the before and after spacing a little.

(Added in edit: in the comments, Style Purist Will recommends adding a little height, and as it's so easy to do - I'd forgotten about the optional argument, myself - I thought it worth adding in the demonstration.  He also used `\linewidth` rather than `\textwidth` - my original choice - which is a little more robust as it will vary correctly in lists and other environments where the linewidth can get altered.)

Comment: @Andrew: Very nice. Just what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend raising that rule a little with something like `\rule[0.5ex]{\linewidth}{1pt}`. I guess that makes me a style purist, whatever that is `;)`

Comment: @Andrew: you'd have gotten hella downvotes if you actually had written up a TiKZ answer. =)

Comment: @Will: I've folded in your suggestions (height and using linewidth).  @Willie: I can see (but maybe you can't) that there has been a TikZ answer to this question, but it got deleted (by its author).  So I was saved the ignominy of the downvotes by Mr X.

Comment: Why not just use `\noindnent\hrulefill` or even just `\hrule` ? Just for the convenience of changing the width or length more easily?

Comment: @frabjous: because I don't use those enough for them to be near the top of my mind!  (I'm particularly intrigued by `\noindnent`, what does that do?)

Comment: It embarasses you on stackexchange when it's too late to edit your post to fix your dumb typo, that's what it does. ;)

Comment: Needing the `\noindent` with `\rule` seems strange. I wonder why it wasn't written to just work in either h mode or v mode. Looking at the definition of `\@rule`, it'd be a trivial modification: remove `\leavevmode\hbox` and replace `\vrule` with `\ifvmode\hrule\else\vrule\fi`

Answer (score 9):

This is more for myself, but I just used `\hrule` where I was trying to use `\hline` in text mode a document, since of course a line is never as simple as just a line. *That's LaTeX.*

Answer (score 6):

I typically use `\hrulefill` or `\noindent\hrulefill` to achieve a horizontal line.